# Search files for information contained in excel cell and return path

Tags: vba, excel

I have found codes from this forum. I have tried very hard to achieve the results but failed on this part. Set f = fs.GetFile(fwb). run time error '53' I am working on Win 7, Office 2013.

I have an Excel spreadsheet with a filename in column A. The filenames listed in column A appear in one or more Ms office .doc files in one or more source directories.

I need Excel to search the .doc files recursively and return the path(s) of the file(s) that contain the filename specified in column A into column B. If more than one file go to column C etc.

I am in dire need of this macro. Please some one help me.

```
    
         __________________________________
         __|______A_____|______B_____|_____
         1 | test_1.doc |c:\cost\test_1.doc|
         2 | test_2.doc |c:\cost\test_2.doc|
```

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
        Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, lr As Long, fPath As String
        Set sh = Sheets(1) 'Change to actual
        lstRw = sh.Cells.Find(
            What:="*", 
            After:=sh.Range("A1"),
            LookAt:=xlPart, 
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, 
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, 
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, 
            MatchCase:=False
        ).Row
        Set rng = sh.Range("A2:A" & lstRw)
        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
            .Show
            fPath = .SelectedItems(1)
        End With
        If Right(fPath, 1) <> "\" Then
            fPath = fPath & "\"
        End If
        fwb = Dir(fPath & "*.*")
        x = 2
        Do While fwb <> ""
            For Each c In rng
                If InStr(LCase(fwb), LCase(c.Value)) > 0 Then
                    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x) = fwb
                    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

                    Set f = fs.GetFile(fwb)  'Run time error '53'

                    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & x) = f.DateLastModified
                    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & x) = f.Path
                    Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A" & x) = c.Value
                    Columns("A:D").AutoFit
                    Set fs = Nothing
                    Set f = Nothing
                    x = x + 1
                End If
            Next
            fwb = Dir
        Loop
        Set sh = Nothing
        Set rng = Nothing
        Sheets(2).Activate
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fwb = Dir(fPath & "*.*")
...
Set f = fs.GetFile(fwb)  'Run time error '53'
```

The Dir(...) function returns only the filename (e.g "myfile.doc") so you have to add the directory path in front of it when calling GetFile(...) :

```
Set f = fs.GetFile(fPath & fwb)
```